# Build failing for mod_caucho, no member named 'remote_ip'?

Tags: apache-2.4, make, resin

I'm trying to get my module to build correctly but it looks like it is having an issue with Apache 2.4. It looks like this is a known issue and a patch was issued for [mod_authnz_external.c](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/issues/attachmentText?id=8&aid=80000000&name=0001-Apache-2.4-compatibility.patch&token=ABZ6GAcZgU8DGfet70_MAD6D51Vp6rh_gA:1401283650395). This unfortunetly does not provide a fix for myself as I am not implementing authnz_external. Here is a dump of my logging.

[configure](http://pastebin.com/6uq3K7n5)

[make](http://pastebin.com/Puyj9nii)

[make install](http://pastebin.com/C7C5p3TP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

```
cd modules/c/src/apache2/
sed -e s/remote_ip/client_ip/g     \
  -e s/remote_addr/client_addr/g   \
  -i mod_caucho.c > mod_caucho.b

mv mod_caucho.b mod_caucho.c
```

remote_* was renamed to client_* in Apache 2.4 ;)